# Share Your Directory across AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, aws-organizations

I have an AWS Organization with four accounts.

I have an AWS Directory Service in one of these accounts. (NOTE: Not in the main one, important)

I'm using this AWS DS to auth my linux machines. I read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/join_linux_instance.html to complete this task.

It's working fine into the account who created the AWS DS

But the instances on the other accounts doesn't reach the AWS DS

Then, I read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/usecase6.html and all the stuff related.

So, as the AWS DS is not into the main account, I only have a chance. Use *Share this directory with other AWS accounts*, ***the handshake***.

I Enabled AWS Organizations -> Settings -> Trusted access for AWS services -> AWS Directory Service.

I created a Share Invitation in the owner of the AWS DS.
I accepted the invitation.
At this point I don't know if a Peering Connetion is needed but I don't care because I have it and works fine.

I tried to join a machine in the account with the invitation without success.

I don't reach, at least, the DNS.

In the machines in acoount who owns the AWS DS...

```sh
root@cthulhu:~# nslookup google.es 18.0.0.75
Server:     13.0.0.55
Address:    13.0.0.55#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.es
Address: 74.125.193.94
Name:   google.es
Address: 2a00:1450:400b:c01::5e

root@cthulhu:~#
```

In the machine in autorized account...

```sh
  root@test-dev01:~# nslookup google.es 13.0.0.55
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

root@test3-dev01:~#
```

Any idea?

**NOTE: I don't want create the AWS DS in the main account in order to use the other method ( "Share this directory with AWS accounts inside your organization").**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys.

It was a route problem. My Peering Conections were fine. My route tables weren't.

Fixed.